# DataGridView , Adjusting width and height to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datagridview

I am binding a DataTable to GridView. It does not adjust to height and width of the DataTable. How can I the strech the width of the grid that i shows all the columns and height shrink if the rows are few.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

---

just go to the properties of your datagrid =>

and then at the section Layout=>

AutoSizeColumnsMode set it to Fill...

Comment: this.ApplicationObjectRecords.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;   it is for  avoid unused column space not row space.

Answer (score 3):

To autosize the columns to fit the data (width-wise) and then autosize the form to fit the gridview (width-wise), use the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

this.Width = dataGridView1.Width + 100;
```

where dataGridView1 is the name of the Datagridview in this example, and `this` is refering to the instance of the form.  The 100 is a constant for how many pixels wider you want the form than the datagridview.  (note: you may want some width checking to make sure you form and data gridview aren't wider than the user's screen)

To autosize the datagridview to fit the rows (height-wise) and then autosize the form to fit the gridview (height-wise), use the following code:

```
int totalRowHeight = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    totalRowHeight += row.Height;

dataGridView1.Height = totalRowHeight;
this.Height = dataGridView1.Height + 100;
```

where dataGridView1 is the name of the Datagridview in this example, and `this` is refering to the instance of the form.  The 100 is a constant for how many pixels higher you want the form than the datagridview.  (note: you may want some height checking to make sure you form and data gridview aren't taller than the user's screen)

Comment: The first part of the answer makes the columns fit the contents of the datagrid, but *does not* make the datagrid to fit its contents (~= the columns).

Answer (score 2):

First, your form would have to be big enough for the DataGridView to expand and show all of the columns.  In the screenshot, it doesn't look wide enough.  You can set the size of the datagridview manually, but it is rare that you know the exact width of each column at design time because you don't know how much will be in each column at run time.  For example, your Invoicedescription column could have strings that vary in length.

What I typically do in cases like yours is to put a splitter control on the form.  The text box at the top and the Import Invoices button would go in the top panel of the splitter control, and the DataGridView would go in the bottom panel.  Then, set the Dock property of the DataGridView to fill the bottom panel of the splitter control.  This way, when the user resizes the form the DataGridView will grow/shrink with it.

You can further control the way the columns appear by setting the DataGridView.AutoResizeRows property.

Just giving this as an option, I'm not aware of any way to have the grid automatically resize to the data it is displaying.  You may be able to calculate the height/width of the rows and then manually resize the grid in code, but I would make sure I really needed that requirement first.

Answer (score 1):

This works assuming that all the rows have the same height, even when the first header row has different height (for example long headers are wrapped)

```
If List.RowCount = 0 Then
  List.Height = 0
ElseIf List.RowCount = 1 Then
  List.Height = List.ColumnHeadersHeight
Else
  List.Height = List.ColumnHeadersHeight + List.Rows(1).Height * (List.RowCount + 1)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the datagridviewautosizecolumn to "All"
Then, in the form that contains the datagridview, assuming you populate the data grid view in the load event handler or some other event handler as desired wherever the data is loaded (must be after data is loaded) type: (VB)

`Me.Width = DataGridView1.Width + 50 ' Number of pixels wider than the datagridview you want the form to be.`

datagridview1 is the name of your datagridview control.
Me refers to the form that contains the datagridview control.

You may need to either maximize the window or anchor it to the top and left to ensure fitment depending on how large of a dataset is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably already answered but just in case I post here what helped me to autosize the whole datagrid view by AllCells:

After your Datasource load, paste the following

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this in IronPyhton to fit the table

1: `LayoutPanel.AutoSize = True`
2: `dataGridView.AutoSize = True`
3: `self.AutoSize = True`